# How to read header values with HttpClient in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

This is the code i'm using

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", HttpContext.Session.GetString("JwtToken"));            

  var url = $"...some url";            

  var requestUri = new Uri(url);

  var responseTask = client.GetAsync(requestUri);
  responseTask.Wait();
           

  var result = responseTask.Result;
  if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
  {
    var reportResults = Task.Run(async() => await result.Content.ReadAsAsync<JArray>()).Result;
    return reportResults;
  }
}
```

Here if i try to access header like this

```
string error = responseTask.Headers.TryGetValue("X-TotalResults").FirstOrDefault();
```

I'm getting error

```
Task<HttpResponseMessage> does not contain a 
definition for Headers and no accessible extension method Headers
```

So How i can read the header .. thanks in advance

Comment: Your method should be marked `async` so you can do `var response = await client.GetAsync(...)` instead of firing an async task and then immediately blocking your thread to wait for the result. Note that `.Wait()` is redundant since `.Result` will always have to wait. As for your error, `responseTask` is the `Task` but you're treating it as its result.

Comment: Also if the method was async you could `await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<JArray>()` without needing to go `Task.Run(...).Result`

Comment: "responseTask" is of type "Task<HttpResponseMessage>" and that does not have a "Headers" property of course. You would need to write  "string error = responseTask.Result.Headers.TryGetValue(....)"

Comment: The extension below helps you to get HttpClient in the form of a curl script.
[Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HttpClientToCurl/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `Task<HttpResponseMessage>` rather than a `HttpResponseMessage`.

Instead of using `.Result`, which is dangerous for many reasons, convert your code to use `async` properly.

```cs
static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

private async JArray GetReportResults()
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", HttpContext.Session.GetString("JwtToken"));            

    var url = $"...some url";            

    using (var response = await client.GetAsync(url))
    {           
        result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
        var reportResults = await result.Content.ReadAsAsync<JArray>();
        return reportResults;
    }
}
```